# compilation error: cast from pointer to integer of different size

Tags: c

I'm using following code:

```
#define OFFSETOF(_s, _m) ((uint32_t)(uint32_t *)(&(((_s *)0)->_m)))

typedef struct test
{
    uint16_t param0;
    uint8_t param1;
} test;

uint32_t uStartAddr = OFFSETOF(test, param1);
```

But I get that error:

```
error: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

Comment: Why are you making up your own `OFFSETOF`? `stddef.h` already has one that is bug free.

Comment: You should be using `muintptr_t` instead of `uint32_t` because you're on a system where pointers are 64 bits, not 32 bits as you assume. This is why you should use the standard macro, too, rather than try to devise your own — at least in code that's supposed to be 'production quality' rather than an exercise. The `offsetof()` macro is peculiar; it can't be a function. But taking the address of an offset from address 0 is iffy — it will usually work, but certainly isn't guaranteed by the standard. That's why the implementation defines `offsetof`; it knows what can be done.

Comment: I can't type — I meant `uintptr_t`, not `muintptr_t`.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Your platform has pointers that are larger than 32 bits. Furthermore, the type of the `offsetof()` expression should be `size_t`. You should either:

- use the standard `offsetof` macro from `<stddef.h>`
- if your compiler does not provide the above definition, use this alternative:

  ```
  #define OFFSETOF(_s, _m) ((size_t)(&((_s *)0)->_m))
  ```
- if you still have problems, try this one:

  ```
  #define OFFSETOF(_s, _m) ((size_t)((char*)&((_s *)0)->_m - (char*)0))
  ```

Comment: It is just that the offsetof is totally utterly wrong, casting the pointer to one of wrong alignment and such...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: of course the portable answer is *use `<stddef.h>`*, but both posted alternative might work.

Comment: If your implementation doesn't provide `offsetof` in `<stddef.h>`, it's non-conforming and is likely to have other problems as well.